# How do I add cookie value in order metadata in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce, metadata

I want the value of cookie `my_cookie` in order metadata.

```php
add_action('init','thankyou_grab_cookie_as_meta_data', 10, 1 );
function thankyou_grab_cookie_as_meta_data( $order_id ){
    if( ! $order_id ){
        return;
    }

    if(isset($_COOKIE["my_cookie"]) && ! get_post_meta( $order_id, 'some default value', true ) ){
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'some default value',  esc_attr($_COOKIE["my_cookie"]) );
    }
}
```

---

The metadata shown now in postman

[image]

Comment: Your question actually **contains too few good details to be able to provide a well-suited answer.** For example, when do you want to assign that data to the order? as soon as the order is created? with a certain order status? front end/back end? to an existing order?
In any case, there will be a better hook suitable than the init hook.. which one? see my additional questions for additional information. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
and [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with the check on ! get_post_meta and then you update_post_meta while it doesn't exists yet. Have update the code below.

```
add_action('init', 'thankyou_grab_cookie_as_meta_data', 10, 1);
function thankyou_grab_cookie_as_meta_data($order_id) {
    if (!$order_id) {
        return;
    }
    if (isset($_COOKIE["my_cookie"])) {
        $my_cookie = esc_attr($_COOKIE["my_cookie"]);
        if (!get_post_meta($order_id, 'some_meta_key', true)) {
            add_post_meta($order_id, 'some_meta_key', $my_cookie);
        } else {
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'some_meta_key', $my_cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

Seems like you are using the WP REST API, maybe you haven't registered the custom field yet. You can use [register_rest_field](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/)

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'custom_register_rest_field');
function custom_register_rest_field() {
    register_rest_field(
        'post', // post type
        'some_meta_key', // meta key
    );
}
```

Comment: Still its not working. I checked the cookie value and everything else just the problem is its not showing in order metadata.

Comment: Are you using the API? What is the url path you are using?

Comment: Have updated my anser give that a try

Comment: URL path: http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/